# JAVA code is not running in vscode showing(connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 127.0.0.1:49407 - Local (127.0.0.1:49418) Error

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I Recently brought a MacBook Air m2 for development. I am facing issue in running java code through vscode  if I run the same code through terminal command then it running properly

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read, this is an error that is often received by Mac users. Visual Studio has stated that they will not address this issue (unless convinced). What I can suggest is to restart your computer.

[You can read from here what says visual studio and more information](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130111)

note: this problem is not caused by java

Answer (score 0):

This is a VS bug with mac as in the opened issue, try disabling VPN so you have the same IP address as suggested here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/130111#issuecomment-918665284

As mentioned also VS will no address the issue for now, if problem still persists maybe you can consider changing to new IDE :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue! However, after some debugging, it turned out my loopback interface was down. To fix this, I ran

```bash
$ sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.1 up
```

See if that helps.